# Making Chrome-like tab resize with pure css

Tags: css

I am trying to create tabs that resize a bit similar to how Chrome tabs does. But I am not sure how and if it is even possible to do without JavaScript.

I don't care about browser support, I only want to see if it can be done with pure html and  css/css3.

Here is the spec:

- The tabs are never wider than the text inside them
- When the right most tab reaches the right side of the window on resize, the tabs should start shrinking (ideal is that this happens to the widest tab first)
- the active tab should never shrink
- As the tabs shrink, the text should be hidden by ellipsis
- the tabs will stop at a min-width that I set (so they can't go to zero width).

Can this be made with something like display: box; and box-flex: 1; properties perhaps? I haven't managed to make it yet. I have already made it with JavaScript. But the performance is not as good as I want it to (this is a BIG wep app).

So, any CSS-Gods out there up for it? If there is a way to do it with very limited use of JavaScript, I am also interested.

Thanks all!

Comment: Javascript for something like this shouldn't cause any performance problems. Can you clarify a little bit about the performance drop and/or provide the javascript that you're using to create this functionality? The reason I ask is because I am not so sure that you can achieve this without any Javascript.

Comment: The javascript performance is slow? I find that surprising...Is your algorithm inefficient, i.e. O(k^n) or O(n!)?

Comment: Ok, I can tell you some more about how my JavaScript does it. I have two classes (Tabs and Tab). A Tab object knows about its initial size, its max-size and its min-size. Tabs  tells each tab (what size it should be). Then when all tabs has a size set, they write the new size to the DOM. It does not have performane issues by itself. But with everything else happening, one window resize can hang for about one to two seconds. So I am trying to optimize as much as possible.

Comment: "The tabs are never wider than the text inside them" Why not? And according to your specifications, unfortunately this cannot be done with pure CSS. Now you can do mostly CSS and have a bit of JS here and there. But it is impossible to do it in CSS. There's a reason JS exists.

Comment: Tyler Crompton: The tabs can be wider than the text inside with some padding. But the point was to make it as simple as possible. I was guessing it was not possible without JS, but wanted to ask here as a final confirmation. And perhaps get some tips on how to do it most efficiently.

Comment: Can you show what you [have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That would make it much easier to suggest improvements, or to find places where JavaScript can be replaced with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close to Chrome's actual behavior with the flexbox...

```
body {
  font: 12px/130% 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; 
}

ul {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: -webkit-box;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}


ul li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 15px 6px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 50px;
  border: solid #ccc 1px;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a656n/

​However, your specs are impossible in CSS only. I'd also suggest that keeping the `active` tab 'unshrunk' breaks conventions because your tabs will change position every time you click on them.

Comment: I don't suppose `li { display: table-cell; }` would work (in part) for non-Webkit browsers, would it?

Answer (score 1):

I improved on Duopixels anwer by using one extra `<span>` element and `display: table-cell` instead of the flexbox implementation. This way you achieve better cross-browser support/fallback. http://jsfiddle.net/w34nm/ (Tested in IE8+, Firefox 10, Chrome 17)

PS: you should probably use JavaScript to set the right width values on the list items

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, your desired functionality is not how tabs in Chrome work, they simply remain a fixed size until there is not enough room, and then they shrink uniformly to fit. (According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-flex), You could accomplish this:

> To make XUL elements in a containing box the same size, set the
>   containing box's equalsize attribute to the value always. This
>   attribute does not have a corresponding CSS property.
>   )

Also, a visual representation of what you are looking for would be very helpful, I found some of the demands rather confusing.

Nonetheless, I've scrapped together [this](http://dabblet.com/gist/1881966). Let me know if it is at all close.

```
ul{
    display: -webkit-box; 
    width:500px; 
    background:lightgray; text-align:left;}
li{background: gray; text-align:center; height:24px; -webkit-box-flex: 1; min-width:30px; max-width:100px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```